# How do I check the version of wxPython installed on my server?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have Python and WxPython installed.
I want to check what is the version of WxPython installed.

Didn't find the answer on https://wxpython.org/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do as follows:

```
>>> import wx
>>> wx.version()
'3.0.2.0 msw (classic)'
>>> wx.__version__
'3.0.2.0'
```

If you want a one-liner on the command-line without using pip (Python 2.7):

```
python -c "import wx;print wx.__version__"
```

Of course in 2022 (Python 3, Python 2 is long gone now) is works like this:

```
python -c "import wx;print(wx.__version__)"
```

Comment: Thanks, By the way is WxPython dead? there hasn't been a realease since 2014.

Comment: The last commit on ``wxPython (classic)`` was [from 2015](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/commits/master). Robin Dunn, the maintainer of wxPython is putting most of his effort into ``wxPython (Phoenix)`` [where development is ongoing](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/commits/master). To get one of these developments builds see [here](https://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython#Installing_wxPython-Phoenix_using_pip), for docs what is different in Phoenix see [here](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/classic_vs_phoenix.html#classic-vs-phoenix).

Comment: @giammi56 Modified your edit request

Answer (score 7):

Just like you would with every other Python library:

`pip show WxPython`

As I don't have this library installed, I can only suggest that some libraries also provide a `__version__` or `version()` attribute.

**EDIT**: [@nepix32's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38845635/1453822) provides the way it was implemented in `WxPython`.

Comment: MMM to check python version I do: `python --version`  no need for PIP. Isn't there a way without PIP?

Comment: @ban I don't know. Some libraries provide a `__version__` attribute, eg `import WxPython ;  WxPython.__version__`.

Comment: @DeepSpace: Have you tried what you have suggested?

Comment: @nepix32 No, as can be understood by my usage of the words "Some", "try" and "I don't know", as I don't have this library installed.